# Enable port 135 on Azure server

Tags: firewall, virtual-machines, azure, rpc, dcom

I have a licensing manager software installed on Azure VM and a client tool tries to connect to it using a DCOM request, which I believe uses port 135. However, I get an 'access is denied' error when it tries to establish a connection.

[Port scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJKNP.png)

I did an nmap scan of the server and as you can see in the image above, it says port 135 is filtered. How do I open it? I believe this might be causing the issue.

[Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDGbV.png)

As you can see in the image above, I have added port 135 to the inbound rules in the security groups section already. I don't know if this group is assigned to the VM instance though.

[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYfBv.png)

Firewall is completely disabled on the server. The DCOM services are set for Everyone in DCOM configuration settings. RPC service is running and set to automatic start.

And finally, here is the actual error I get:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAQSM.png)

I've been trying to fix this without success for days, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely middle box firewall, either ISP firewall or otherwise since exposing that Port to the internet unencrypted is a terrible idea.

Comment: Also, removing the first 2 octets isn't the best privacy... Since azure ranges are public knowledge https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653

Comment: Do you check the server is running? Please show the result `netstat -ant|findstr 135`

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: Server is running according to Azure dashboard. Here is a screenshot of netstat: https://i.imgur.com/TycDLMj.png

Comment: @JacobEvans: I don't think it's an ISP firewall since my colleague who is at a different location gets the same error.

Comment: I assume you both have an internet service provider...  https://www.google.com/search?q=port+135+isp+block&oq=port+135+isp+block&aqs=chrome..69i57.9529j0j4&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Inception Do you use classic VM or ARM mode VM?

Comment: @Inception If possible, could you show your VM public IP, I want to test connection.

Comment: @Inception For test port 135 connection, you could try `telnet IP 135`

Comment: @JacobEvans: Sorry, I should have been more specific. My colleagues at two different countries were getting the same error, hence why I presumed it's not an ISP block. Also, I just googled port 135 block for my ISP and didn't see any reported cases.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: I believe it is classic VM. I do not remember ever selecting ARM mode VM while creating the instance. Public IP is: 40.118.70.104

Comment: @Inception For a classic VM, you need create a endpoint for port 135. Please refer this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST have a private network connection to communicate over known insecure ports.  This is where you must use things like IPSEC VPN, DMVPM, MPLS, SD-WAN.

Port 135, among MANY others are blocked.

http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r7673039-Per-homeland-security-qwest-blocking-ports
https://www.xfinity.com/support/internet/list-of-blocked-ports/

An Easy solution would be to install Something like ZeroTier on your server and cients, free for up to 100 endpoints.

Comment: Can you help me out on using this? I have installed it on both server and client, I created an account and a network. I managed to connect to the network using the ID on both server and client, now what should I do?

Comment: Use the new server IP on the Private interface to connect

Comment: Hi Jacob, quick question, would the same solution work on AWS EC2 instances as well? I had the exact same issue on EC2 hence why I thought of trying Azure. Now that there is a potential solution, I was thinking maybe I can go back to my preferred AWS if it works.

Comment: Yes the above solution is provider agnostic

Comment: Ah alright. When I connect on both server and client machines, it shows up in the 'Members' section in my ZeroTier account. But which new server IP are you talking about? Do you mean the one under 'Managed Routes'? By default it reads 172.23.0.0 and I can pick other addresses as well.

Comment: Pick what you want, you should read the docs and stop setup a basic ACL, you can also make the server static.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe it is classic VM. I do not remember ever selecting ARM mode
> VM while creating the instance.

For a classic VM, you need create an endpoint for port 135. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints#create-an-endpoint).

[image]

Update:

According to long chatting, it seems Azure NSG and firewall configuration is all right. Your ISP and company firewall also could block port 135, you have a choice. Creating a [point-to-site VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal). Access your server with private IP(not public).

Comment: Extremely sorry for my ignorance, but it seems I'm not on classic VM as it simply displays 'Virtual machine' without classic on my dashboard. And I do not have Endpoints settings tab either.

Comment: @Inception But the port is not enable, https://imgur.com/a/pDTku . Currently, it is a firewall issue. If you want to access it from public IP, you need ensure you could access the port.

Comment: I have added an inbound security rule to enable port 135: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDGbV.png Is there anything else I have to do to enable it?

Comment: @Inception Azure NSG could be associated to Azure NIC and VNet subnet, do you all check it. In your resource group, do you find how many NSG resource?

Comment: @Inception You could check like [this](https://imgur.com/a/89zmF).

Comment: It does not show subnet in the dashboard: https://i.imgur.com/NhCcOgn.png  
NewRG2 is the Resource group name. https://i.imgur.com/A07AUGy.png
Here are all the resource groups: https://i.imgur.com/Xns8D74.png

Comment: Hi, could you show resources in the resource group?

Comment: Here is the resource group page: https://i.imgur.com/m1q5lsg.png

Comment: Azure NSG should be right. For test, could you create a VM in the same VNet and test connect your server with private IP.

Comment: As Jacob Evans said, your ISP or company network maybe block port 135.

Comment: @Inception If your ISP or company firewall block port 135, you could create [a point-to-site VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal). Then you could access your server with private IP.

Comment: Thank you Walter. Should I try Zerotier or the one you just suggested?. Is there a recommended way?

Comment: For a Azure VM, I suggest you could use a point-to-site VPN, but you need use private IP to connect your service from your local PC.

Comment: Alright, I'm trying it out. For the 'address range' and 'Address space', should I use the default values? https://i.imgur.com/XYebfux.png

Comment: Hi, don't overlap for your local address.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Should I give my private IP in both fields?

Comment: Hi, if your local is 192.168.*.*. You could use the default one. If your local address ranges is 10.0.0.*, you need change the default one.

Comment: It is 10.0.. So I should change both address space and range to 10.0.0.0/24 right?  Here is ipconfig on server: https://i.imgur.com/voQQnsH.png

Comment: For Azure VNet, you could not 10.1.0.0/24. Your local IP is 10.0.0.0/24. But I suggest you could use 172.168.0.0/16 for VNet because you could use more IP ranges.

Comment: Hi, if you have question about Azure, you also could send e-mail to me. `v-shshui@hotmail.com`

Comment: I get this when I try to create gateway subnet: https://i.imgur.com/pL5uXYt.png

Comment: What is your default subnet. When you create VNet, VNet should be 172.168.0.0/16, default subnet is 172.168.0.0/24. Gateway subnet could be `172.168.1.0/24`. Default subnet don't use all IP ranges.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But now in the next step(Create a virtual network gateway), I'm stuck after clicking 'Create' in Create network gateway page).. https://i.imgur.com/vqN4KBn.png

Comment: It seems a browser issue, could you refresh your browser or change other browser.

Comment: Hi, currently could you create vpn gateway?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I just finished creating certificates. Now in point-to-site configuration, what value should I give in 'Address Pool'?

Comment: Your local IP subnet, it should be `10.0.0.0/24`.

Comment: When the VPN is connected, you could test RDP your VM with private IP firstly, then test port 135 connection. Using `telnet <private IP> 135`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake... Your VM should be in the VNet(172.168.0.0/16). If your VM is not in it, you need create a new one or migrate to it.

Comment: I have still not finished creating VPN gateway. I'm stuck in step 9, I did point-to site configuration: https://i.imgur.com/flf04pp.png Then after I download and install VPN client, when I try to connect it, I get error: https://i.imgur.com/y28NKt6.png

Comment: Do you check your local certificate, according to the error log, it seems could not find your local certificate.

Comment: You install certificate on your PC, step 8?

Comment: I generated the certificate on this PC. Do I need to install it again? I skipped step 8 because of this,

Comment: I suggest you install it.

Comment: I'm still getting that error. In step 5, after the thumprint step, is it supposed to display something? I get no output: https://i.imgur.com/ZHo1vvm.png

Comment: Hi, could you execute `certmgr.msc ` and check like this https://imgur.com/a/ivsTR

Comment: It shows the certificate: https://i.imgur.com/L8m1mrR.png

Comment: @Inception If your step is right, the certificate is right. Could you check your step again. I test in my lab before, the link works for me.

Comment: OK now it worked, however I'm still getting 'Access is denied' error when I try to connect :(

Comment: Do you mean VPN connect or connect your license server?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I can connect to VPN, but not to the license manager.

Comment: Your VM should in the VNet which has VPN gateway, also, you could not access your service with public IP(ISP block port 135). You connect your service with private IP(VPN tunnle directly to your service).

Comment: You should ensure you could rdp to your VM with private IP. Azure VPN connection could help you bypass ISP firewall directly to Azure.

Comment: Oh, I'm not able to connect to it using private IP. It says RDP maybe disabled, or machine may be turned off etc. The private IP is 10.0.0.4.

Comment: Could you ping 10.0.0.4 from your local PC? Now, Windows Firewall is disabled, you could ping it.

Comment: Pinging did not work. Firewall is completely disabled, also I'm connected to the VPN.

Comment: No, your Azure VNet ip address is 172.168.0.0/16? Your Azure VM is 10.0.0.4? No, your VM should be in the VNet.

Comment: Your local create a VPN connection from your local to Azure VNet, your Azure VM should be in the VNet. If it is not in it, you could not connect it with private IP.

Comment: If possible, you could create a new VM and install license software in it.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without creating new VM? I think the current VM is in old Vnet: https://i.imgur.com/fAZc2P8.png 
VNet1 is the one I created today: https://i.imgur.com/JfWIS5m.png

Comment: I check it, no your VM is not in your VPN gateway VNet. You use managed disk, if you want to migrate to new VNet, you need copy VM's VHD to stroage account and use the VHD to create VM.

Comment: If possible, I suggest you could create a new VM. I think it is save more time. Note: VPN gateway is expensive.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, at the beginning, I did not remind you of this..

Comment: Hi, I need go home in my country, if you have question, you could post here or e-mail me :--)

Comment: Hi, that is perfectly fine, thanks a lot for your help. I will keep in touch. Let me try to migrate it.

Comment: One another question, does this VPN gateway I created cost extra money? Also, will using Zerotier help me avoid migrating the subnet step and save money?

Comment: Hi, Zerotier is a software, if you install it on Azure VM, maybe you need open some ports. If you use point-to-site VPN, after you use it, you could delete VPN gateway.

Comment: Sorry I am not in office, if you have question, I will answer you tomorrow.